# Загрузка файлов в битрикс с исходным названием

Tags: файлы, битрикс, загрузка

Возник такой вопрос. Везде уже пересмотрел, но не могу понять почему, когда я загружаю файл с проставленными галочками в следующих пунктах
[image: Проставлены галочки Сохранять исходные имена файлов и Производить транслитерацию имени файла]

Но по какой-то причине битрикс напрочь отказывается сохранять исходные имена файлов. Ниже показана ссылка на файл с произвольным набором букв и цифр, а не имя файла, которое ожидаешь увидеть
[image: Название превратилось в набор букв и цифр]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос. Проблема была в том, что до того как были проставлены галочки документ уже загружался и ему присвоился набор букв и цифр вместо названия. Когда галочки проставились и я попытался повторно загрузить файл, то название не поменялось, потому что некоторые другие элементы ссылались на данный документ. Поэтому сначала нужно удалить все связи, а потом уже загружать файл